# deleteOnExit not working after extracting file from executing jar

Tags: java

In an simple java application I have code to extract an file from jar to `Temp` location, I marked that extracting file to delete when VM terminates but when execution of jar is finished file won't get deleted.

Main Class:

```
java.io.File parentFolder = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "MyApp");
            if (!parentFolder.exists()) {
                parentFolder.mkdir();
            }
            parentFolder.deleteOnExit();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "MyApp" + File.separator + "MyApp.exe");
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(URLDecoder.decode(MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(), "utf-8"));
            BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(bin);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {               
                if (ze.getName().contains("MyApp.exe")) {
                    java.io.File f = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "MyApp" + File.separator + ze.getName());
                    f.deleteOnExit();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    out.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            zin.close();
            bin.close();
            fin.close();
            Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "MyApp" + File.separator + "MyApp.exe");
            child.waitFor();
```

Is there anything wrong here?

**Update**

It's working Now :)

previously `MyApp.exe` file is kept parallel to the `MainClass.Class` file i.e in `src/MainApp/MyApp.exe` I moved .exe file to `src/MyApp.exe` so after building to jar .exe is at root level. So after executing the jar .exe get extracted to temp folder and deleted when jar Finish its work.

Why it's not working with previous location (`src/MainApp/MyApp.exe`)?

Comment: On a side note, delete on exit is evil :D https://puneeth.wordpress.com/2006/01/23/filedeleteonexit-is-evil/

Comment: Okay, Though Why above code is not working :)

Comment: I tried commenting last two lines still not working

Comment: Maybe a stream is not closed properly. Sorround it with a try block and insert a finally where you close the streams, i think the relevant one would be the out stream. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28751091/4807777

Comment: Small change in location of .exe file and its working now See the update part of question