# Temp file won't delete on exit - why is this?

Tags: java, file

I am trying to delete these temp files on exit:
- "hsperfdata_user"
- "JNativeHook-2.1.0"
- "jna-196922"

It doesn't appear that they are deleting!

```
if (temp != null) {
    for (File file : temp.listFiles()) {
        if (file.getName().contains("JNative") || file.getName().contains("rar") || file.getName().contains("hsper") || file.getName().contains("jna") || file.getName().contains("dll")) {
            file.deleteOnExit();
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

The "duplicate" question refers to deleting files that you have created - I haven't created these temp. files deliberately. They create automatically.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what `temp` contains (let alone its type). `temp` might have nothing in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleteOnExit not deleting file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758520/deleteonexit-not-deleting-file)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I can see the temp files there though - they don't delete.

Comment: see proposed duplicate **and** check user rights on the file

Comment: Have you verified that the `deleteOnExit` branch is actually reached?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on Windows because the DLL is still loaded into the VM when it tries to delete itself.  If it's a problem, the file should be permanently unpacked to the installation location and the appropriate `java.library.path` set.  I would like to reiterate that this is not possible because java does not provide an `System.unload(...)` method to remove the library from the JVM safely due to technical restriction.

It maybe possible: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues/148#issuecomment-282173982